# Replace a char in a text file using powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I'm trying to replace a part on a text file.
First i searched if it is present in the text file

```
$check = Get-Content sample.txt | Where-Object {$_.Contains('<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="7" />')}

if ($checkIISv)
{
Write-Host "IIS's version is already 7"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Update IIS version to 7"

# I want to place here a code that will replace the value="7" if it is not =7
# This value is usually not 7

}
```

Please help, I dont think the replace function can be used here since the "value" is considered as unknown.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `-replace` with a regex-pattern to replace the value. However, this is an web/app xml-config so you should modify it as an XML-document. Ex.

```
#$xml = [xml](Get-Content "c:\folder\app.config")
$xml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="IIS_VERSION" value="8" />
    <add key="somekey" value="somevalue" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
"@

$IISVersion = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='IIS_VERSION']")

if ($IISVersion.Value -eq 7)
{
    Write-Host "IIS's version is already 7"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Update IIS version to 7"
    $IISVersion.Value = "7"
}

$xml.Save("c:\folder\app.config")
```

Comment: thats probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the line is always there you can of course use `-replace`. It does a regex replace, which can be used here:

```
$content = Get-Content sample.txt
if ($content -match '<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="7" />') {
  Write-Host "IIS's version is already 7"
} else {
  Write-Host "Update IIS version to 7"
  $content -replace '<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="[^"]+" />', '<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="7" />'
}
```

That's about the simplest way of doing that when using a string replace.

However, your file looks very much like XML. In which case it should actually be easier to use XML manipulation, which PowerShell offers as well:

```
$content = [xml](Get-Content sample.txt)
$iisKey = $content.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key = 'IIS_VERSION']")
if ($iisKey.value -eq 7) {
  Write-Host "IIS's version is already 7"
} else {
  Write-Host "Update IIS version to 7"
  $iisKey.value = '7'
  $content.Save((Resolve-Path sample.txt))
}
```

(Untested, and I don't do that often, but should be something alone those lines.)

Comment: Thank you! I used your 1st script and just added " | Set-Content sample.txt" however I would like to understand this, what does this [^"] stands for? is it some kind of a wild card characters?

Comment: I'm about to edit a couple of lines but it seems that the only one it edits is the last statement

Comment: `[^"]+` is a regular expression that matches a string of character that are not a quotation marks. This is an easy way of specifying all text between two delimiters, in this case, everything between two quotation marks.

Comment: thanks for this, anyway I have posted the updated script using your suggestion, however when I create another set to update another line the only one that changes is the last one, see my post. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The content looks like XML so you should consider using an xpath expression to select the node and change the value (See the [answer from Frode F.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37220728/1163423)). However, you can also do this with a regex (using a positive lookbehind to find the position)

```
$txt = Get-Content sample.txt
$regex = '(?<=<add key="IIS_VERSION" value=")[^"]+'
$txt -replace $regex, 7
$txt | Set-Content sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem now is that it it only updates the bar code format and no longer the iis version if it is lower than 7

$path ='C:\Users\hello\Documents'

```
#Update the IIS version to 7

$content = Get-Content $path\Web.config

if ($content -match '<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="7" />') 
{
  Write-Host "IIS's version is already 7"
} 
else 
{
  Write-Host "Updated IIS version to 7"
  $content -replace '<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="[^"]+" />', '<add key="IIS_VERSION" value="7" />' | Set-Content $path\sample.txt
}


# Update the Barcode Format

if ($content -match '<add key="BARCODE_FORMAT" value="1" />')
{
    Write-Host "Barcode format is already 1"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Updated Barcode Format to 1"
    $content -replace '<add key="BARCODE_FORMAT" value="[^"]+" />', '<add key="BARCODE_FORMAT" value="1" />' | Set-Content $path\sample.txt
}
```

Comment: We don't get a notification if you add a new answer. Use comments on the specific answer. Your problem happened because you include `set-content` inside your if-test, so it writes to the file twice (and the last overwrites the first with only barcode modified). If you changed to `$content = $content -replace ...` inside the tests (without any `set-content`) and use `$content | set-content` in the end of the script, it would work.  Or use my approach which already does this. The barcode part was never a part of the question so you would need to expand my answer if you want to use it.